# MySQL DB replication hook to clean local cache

Tags: mysql, replication

I have the app a MySQL DB is a slave for other remote Master DB. And i use memcache to do caching of some DB data.

My slave DB can be updated if there are updates in a Master DB. So in my application i want to know when my local (slave) DB is updated to invalidate related cached data and display fresh data i got from master.

Is there any way to run some program when slave mysql DB is updated ? i would then filter q query and understand if i need to clean a cache or not.

Thanks

Comment: Is your slave in the same datacenter as master ?

Comment: No. It can be in different datacenter

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are looking for solution similar to what Facebook did in their  db architecture (As I remember they patched MySQL for this).

You can build your own solution based on one of these techniques:

- Parse replication log on slave side, remove cache entry when you see update of data in the log
- Load UDF (user defined function) for memcached, attach trigger on replica side (it will call UDF remove function) to interested tables inside MySQL.

Please note that this configuration is complicated during the support and maintenance. If you can sacrifice stale data in the cache maybe small ttl will help you.

Answer (score 0):

As Kirugan says, it's as simple as writing your own SQL parser, and ensuring that you also provide an indexed lookup keyed to the underlying data for anything you insert into the cache, then cross reference the datasets for any DML you apply to the database. Of course, this will be a lot simpler if you create a simplified, abstract syntax to represent the DML, but thereby losing the flexibilty of SQL and of course, having to re-implement any legacy code using your new syntax. Apart from fixing the existing code, it should only take a year or two to get this working right. Basing your syntax on MySQL's handler API rather than SQL will probably save a lot of pain later in the project.

Of course, if you need full cache consistency then you need to ensure that a logical transaction now spans all the relevant datacentres which will have something of an adverse impact on your performance (certainly much slower than just referencing the master directly).

For a company like facebook, with hundreds of thousands of servers and terrabytes of data (and no requirement for cache consistency) such an approach to solving the problem leads to massive savings. If you only have 2 servers, a better solution would be to switch to multi-master replication, possibly add another database node, optimize the storage (e.g. switching to ssds / adding fast bcache) make sure you have session affinity to the dbms from the aplication (but not stcky sessions) and spend some time tuning your dbms, particularly its cache performance.